# Prevent from multiple ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some content that I get with help of ajax. Also in this content I need to do some ajax too, so I use .ajaxComplete()
Here is how I want to do this.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
$(".deleteParticipant").click(function(){
    var id={id:$(this).parent().parent().find('td#idOfParticipant').html()};
    $.ajax({
        url:"delete.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: id,
        async: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
$(".editParticipant").click(function(){
    var id={id:$(this).parent().parent().find('td#idOfParticipant').html()};
    $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: id,
        async: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Everything works fine, but when I click on .deleteParticipant or .editParticipant second time it calls two ajax queries, when 3 - 4 etc. What is the best way to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time a `ajaxComplete` event fires, you're binding one more event handler. Hence the multiple calls. Use event delegation instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteParticipant", function() {
    var id={id:$(this).parent().parent().find('td#idOfParticipant').html()};
    $.ajax({
        url:"delete.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: id,
        async: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}).on("click", ".editParticipant", function() {
    var id={id:$(this).parent().parent().find('td#idOfParticipant').html()};
    $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: id,
        async: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```